# How to get a smooth move?

Tags: android, android-animation

Hi I am not getting a smooth move, in my game train moves front and back it is nice, but train movement is not smooth(like not train move fixed speed and smooth). Please help............

```
public void run() {
Canvas canvas = null;

while (mRun) {
    long beginTimeMillis, timeTakenMillis, timeLeftMillis;
    canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
    if (canvas != null) {
         beginTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        gp.doDraw(canvas);
        gp.animate();
        timeTakenMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTimeMillis;
        timeLeftMillis = (1000L / 30) - timeTakenMillis;
        Log.i("timeLeftMillis"+timeLeftMillis,"");
        mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        if (timeLeftMillis < 5) { 
            timeLeftMillis = 5; 

        }
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(timeLeftMillis);  
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }
    }

   }
 }
```

Edit: I don't know how to use the thread while getting a smooth move.

Answer (score 0):

are you using View or SurfaceView. If your using View, use surfaceview. It will make your application much smoother.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am using surfaceview, but i am not getting smooth move.I am not understand how to handle smooth move.My train is not moving constant speed. please help me.

Comment: did you use anti aliasing in Paint ?

Comment: No, I am using bitmap and draw image. my problem is train speed is not correct. Train moves some distance is slow and next it will move speed.code is correct x increment +1 every time.I think problem is in thread to maintain fps.